# How to SCP from remote Windows to host Linux if the source path has more than 8 sub-directory levels?

Tags: windows, scp

I have a remote windows machine with built in openssh server on it.
I tried to `scp` a folder named `0` from my home dir in remote Windows to local Downloads:

```
scp -r micro:0 Downloads/
```

The results in local host:

```
Downloads/0
```

Then I added subfolder `1` in `0` in remote windows and ran `scp` again. The results in local host:

```
Downloads/0
└── 1
```

I kept adding subfolders until `7`. The results in local host:

```
Downloads/0
└── 1
    └── 2
        └── 3
            └── 4
                └── 5
                    └── 6
                        └── 7
```

Then I added the 8th level. The `scp` command failed and didn't create `8` folder. The output:

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host micro, user (unspecified), command scp -v -r -f 0
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ali/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/ali/.ssh/config line 45: Applying options for micro
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to micro [192.168.1.178] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ali/.ssh/ali type 0
debug1: identity file /home/ali/.ssh/ali-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to micro:22 as 'ali'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ******
debug1: Host 'micro' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ali/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ali/.ssh/ali RSA SHA256:****** explicit agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/ali/.ssh/ali RSA SHA256:****** explicit agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/ali/.ssh/ali RSA SHA256:****** explicit agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to micro ([192.168.1.178]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -f 0
Entering directory: D0777 0 0
Sink: D0777 0 0
Entering directory: D0777 0 1
Sink: D0777 0 1
Entering directory: D0777 0 2
Sink: D0777 0 2
Entering directory: D0777 0 3
Sink: D0777 0 3
Entering directory: D0777 0 4
Sink: D0777 0 4
Entering directory: D0777 0 5
Sink: D0777 0 5
Entering directory: D0777 0 6
Sink: D0777 0 6
Entering directory: D0777 0 7
Sink: D0777 0 7
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3044, received 3552 bytes, in 2.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 1387.7, received 1619.3
debug1: Exit status -1073741571
```

This problem seems to be unrelated to long file path. I tried to move `0` to `~/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/` in remote and `scp -r micro:a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/0 Downloads/` worked fine without `8` folder.

How can I use `scp` with more than 8 sub-directory levels under source path?

Answer (score 0):

This is your error message:

```
debug1: Exit status -1073741571
```

Error code `-1073741571` is the signed decimal representation of
hexadecimal error code 0xC00000FD, which for Windows stands for
stack overflow or stack exhausted.
This normally happens when recursion is too deep and the program's
stack is too small.

The question is whether the problem is on the server or the client.

I take it that on the remote server you use a Windows built-in application.
I suggest replacing it by an OpenSSH server.

If the problem disappears, you now know that the problem was on the server
and is now solved. If it doesn't disappear, then you need to replace
the client software.

Comment: I can scp from other remotes on this client without this problem. The problem should be in server.